# mat-list-option (click) without actually selecting item

Tags: angular

Currently `mat-list-option` accepts binding of click event but it does not differentiate between (click) and the default select action.
Using `$event.preventDefault()` or `$event.stopPropagation()` will not make a difference. A click on the checkbox will trigger the click event too.

Is there any solution to bind a click event without having the item selected and have the selection change only when the checkbox is clicked ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-list-option (click)="simpleAction($event)">

simpleAction(event){
    if(this.selectionList.selectedOptions.selected.length == 1 && event.target.tagName === 'DIV'){
        this.selectionList.deselectAll()
        ... perform some action for single item click ...
    }
```